# Is there an accepted age range for peak creativity?

Tags: creativity

I have noticed in myself, and others (from afar) that creativity seems to decline with age.

Physically, it's obvious that people peak rather early (say, 25 or 30 or so years of age). But what about when it comes to creativity? Is there a known age range that are typically the most creative years?

If you compare the works of great artists (and I know there are also many exceptions/outliers), it seems most of their "greatest" works came earlier in life (for those that lived long lives, that is).

Just a few examples of those who seemed most creative in their younger years, when more of their "masterpieces" were created, are:

```
Music: Dylan, Browne, Springsteen
Literature: Twain, Steinbeck, London
```

I'll leave it to others to add more examples, or refute these.

Comment: Hi Clay, it seems that you link creativity to the quality of the produced songs/books. However, given people's differing taste, people's thoughts on the age men is at their peak creativity will be greatly influenced by their opinion. Unless there is some formal way to quantify creativity, I think this question may be closed for being opinion based.

Comment: The question hinges on *...most of their "greatest" works came earlier in life...*. What is great? What is greatest? According to who? What is *earlier* in life? Without strictly defining these variables and backing the premise (creativity goes down with age) up with supporting sources I don't think this question is answerable within our scope.